# Unable to serve NextJS static assets through Nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass, static-files

I have a NextJS app running on port 3000 and I have a `test.ico` file located at the following location:

```
/static/images/icons/
```

I want this file to be served off the root rather than the actual path. I mean instead of **https://www.schandillia.com/static/images/icons/test.ico**, I want it to be available as **https://www.schandillia.com/test.ico**. I can easily configure my Express server to serve this file but I want to let Nginx handle this. So I have the following configuration added to my Nginx conf server block:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    charset UTF-8;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
  }
  location /test.ico {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/static/images/icons/test.ico;
    expires 365d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
  }
  location ~* \.(?:ico|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|otf|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
   expires 365d;
   add_header Pragma public;
   add_header Cache-Control "public";
  }
```

However, **https://www.schandillia.com/test.ico** is now throwing a 404. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *regular expression* `location` takes precedence over regular *prefix* `location` blocks. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

You can change the precedence order by using any of these instead:

```
location = /test.ico
location ^= /test.ico
location ~ ^/test.ico
```